# Checkbox element passing data to parent with useEffect

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, react-hooks

As a React beginner exercice I have a component checkbox for a list of devices. If a device is checked, I want my App parent element to display the name of the device. I tried several ways to do it but cannot achieve it.
Here is my code

Checkbox.jsx

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"

const Checkbox = ({ label, name, sendData}) => {
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false);

  const handleChange =() => {
    setIsChecked({isChecked: !isChecked} )
  }
  
  useEffect(()=> {
      sendData(isChecked)
  })

  return (
    <div className="checkbox-wrapper">
      <label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={isChecked }
          onChange={handleChange}
          name={name}
        />
        <span>{label}</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Checkbox;
```

App.js

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import Checkbox from './components/Checkbox';
import './App.css';
```

```js
import { useState } from 'react';
import Checkbox from './components/Checkbox';
import './App.css';

function App() {

  const [ownDevice, setOwnDevice] = useState(false)

  const sendData = (childData) => {
    setOwnDevice(childData)
  }

  const displayDevice = (Checkbox) => {
     if (ownDevice) {
       return Checkbox.name
     }
  }

return(
  <div className="App">
    <h1>What devices do you own?</h1>
    <Checkbox label="laptop" name="laptop" sendData={sendData} />
    <Checkbox label="desktop" name="desktop" />
    <Checkbox label="phone" name="phone" />
    <p>{displayDevice}</p>
  </div>

)


}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solved your problem this way, hope it helps:

```
function App() {
  const [ownDevice, setOwnDevice] = useState(false)
  const [displayName, setDisplayname] = useState('')
  const sendData = (childData) => {
    setOwnDevice(childData)
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
    <h1>What devices do you own?</h1>
    <Checkbox label="laptop" name="laptop" sendData={sendData}
    setOwnDevice={setOwnDevice}
    />
    <Checkbox label="desktop" name="desktop" sendData={sendData}
    setOwnDevice={setOwnDevice}
    />
    <Checkbox label="phone" name="phone"  sendData={sendData}
    setOwnDevice={setOwnDevice}
    />
    <p>{ownDevice}</p>
  </div>
  );
}
```

CheckBox file :

```
const Checkbox = ({ label, name, sendData,setOwnDevice}) => {
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false);

  const handleChange =(e) => {
    setIsChecked(true)
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setOwnDevice(name)
  }
  

  return (
    <div className="checkbox-wrapper">
      <label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={isChecked }
          onChange={handleChange}
          name={name}
        />
        <span>{label}</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the code you have written will be stuck in an infinite render loop if we update the parent state on changing the `isChecked` state because you haven't provided a dependency to `useEffect` which means it will update the parent state every time your component renders.

You need to remove the `useEffect` altogether. And secondly you can simple pass the `setOwnDevice` method directly to the child. The child will update the parent state which will result in a rerender. We can then use that state to display the selected device. The updated `Checkbox.jsx` component will look like this:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"

const Checkbox = ({ label, name,  setOwnDevice}) => {
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false);

  const handleChange =() => {
    setIsChecked(!isChecked)  
    setOwnDevice(name)
  }

  return (
    <div className="checkbox-wrapper">
      <label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={isChecked}
          onChange={handleChange}
          name={name}
        />
        <span>{label}</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Checkbox;
```

Then update the `App.js` file:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Checkbox from './components/Checkbox';
import './App.css';

function App() {

  const [ownDevice, setOwnDevice] = useState("")

return(
  <div className="App">
    <h1>What devices do you own?</h1>
    <Checkbox label="laptop" name="laptop" setOwnDevice={setOwnDevice} />
    <Checkbox label="desktop" name="desktop" setOwnDevice={setOwnDevice} />
    <Checkbox label="phone" name="phone" setOwnDevice={setOwnDevice} />
    <p>{ownDevice}</p>
  </div>

)


}

export default App;
```

This could still be improved further because currently it won't show two checked devices at the same time.

Comment: thanks @hassansuhaib  the logic works, but the checkboxes are not unchecked visually when clicked twice. How could I fix this issue?

Comment: I can't say. Maybe you'll have to investigate some more.

Comment: The problem came from this line in the Checkbox handleChange method:

    setIsChecked({isChecked: !isChecked} )

it has to be : 
    setIsChecked( !isChecked )